# Problema generar reporte Netbeans + Jasperreport

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, ireport

Quiero generar un sencillo reporte PDF, y empecé por generar un PDF estático (sin bases de datos) para confirmar que funciona correctamente, pero no va!
He miradotutoriales de todo tipo, descargado ejemplos... creon quen es problema de librerías, he descargado todo los jar de https://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/latest/download

Tengo estas librerías agregadas al proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el código para ver el reporte que he generado con el Wizard del Plugin de Netbeans es este:

```
 @FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws JRException, IOException {
    System.out.println("You clicked me!");
    label.setText("Hello World!");
    
    // obtenemos la plantilla JRXML como un stream
    
    String reporte ="C:\\Users\\jualex\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaFXApplication1\\src\\javafxapplication1\\newReport1.jasper";
    HashMap parameters = new HashMap();
    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, null);

    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, "C:\\Users\\jualex\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaFXApplication1\\src\\javafxapplication1\\PruebaPDF.pdf");
}
```

Y los errores que aparecen son estos:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:410)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:941)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:185)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistry
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForRealName(JRClassLoader.java:190)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForName(JRClassLoader.java:148)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ClassUtils.instantiateClass(ClassUtils.java:60)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.instantiateRegistry(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:298)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.loadRegistries(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:274)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.loadRegistries(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:194)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getRegistries(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:157)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:129)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser.<clinit>(JRStyledTextParser.java:86)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:116)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:79)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createBandReportFiller(JRFiller.java:251)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createReportFiller(JRFiller.java:272)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:210)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:362)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:862)
    at javafxapplication1.FXMLDocumentController.handleButtonAction(FXMLDocumentController.java:40)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 77 more
```

Espero que alguien me facilite qué librerías exactamente debo tener. He porbado instalando Ant en Windows, porque leí algo de eso tb.
Es una aplicación de escritorio en JavaFX.
**Espero vuestra ayuda! Gracias :)**

Comment: En efecto, te faltan algunas librerías. Te recomiendo que uses Maven para gestionar las dependencias de tu proyecto. Es un poco complicado al principio pero cuando aprendes a usarlo vas sobre ruedas. Las librerías se indican en el archivo `pom.xml` y Maven las agrega a tu proyecto. Maven tiene también una página donde aparece cada librería, allí tomarías la versión más reciente copiando el código de debes poner en `pom.xml` para que esa librería se agregue a tu proyecto.

Comment: Por ejemplo, [esta es la página para Jasper Report](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports). Allí obtendrás la última versión que es de Noviembre 2020 en este momento, tomas el código para agregar el artefacto y lo pegas en tu `pom.xml` y Maven cargará la librería. El código se obtiene haciendo click en el número de versión. Otra posibilidad es usar Gradle (si tienes experiencia programando en Android posiblemente te suene). Ant también es posible, pero es mucho más antiguo que Maven y que Gradle.

Comment: Pero puedo utilizar Maven con JavaFX??

Comment: Claro que sí. JavaFX es Java. No recuerdo ahora si en NetBeans hace falta un plugin, pero recuerdo haber hecho algún programa JavaFX desde NetBeans usando Maven. No recuerdo ahora si entre las opciones, cuando seleccionas nuevo proyecto, aparece una "JavaFX con Maven" o algo así. Lo que si recuerdo que la configuración inicial fue un poco complicada, pero era sobre todo porque no tenía idea de Maven en ese entonces.

Comment: Pero puedo utilizar Maven con JavaFX?? El problema es que ya tengo un proyecto hecho en JavaFX, y quería añadir la opción de generar reportes en PDF y CSV ¿Cómo le incluyo Maven y el archivo pom.xml a un proyecto que ya está hecho como Aplicación JavaFX FXML ? Buscaré a ver algún plugin que permita "adaptar" el proyecto a Maven.

Comment: Prueba a seleccionar "Nuevo Proyecto" (New Project) en tu menú de NetBeans. Allí debería aparecer una opción llamada "Java with Maven"  y cuando haces clic en ella aparecen otras opciones, podrías escoger "Simple JavaFX Maven Archetype", si no tienes el plugin te dirá que tienes que descargarlo/activarlo, lo cual haces. Cuando eso ocurra te creará un nuevo proyecto muy simple con una clase `Main`  (te pedirá el nombre del proyecto y otras cosas). Luego puedes migrar tu antiguo proyecto a ese nuevo proyecto (sólo las clases y demás), las librerías las agregas desde el `pom.xml`

Comment: Acabo de hacer una prueba con [Apache NetBeans 12](https://netbeans.apache.org/) (es la nueva versión de NetBeans creada por Apache, que terminará siendo la definitiva) y el proceso es mucho más simple que hace años, recuerdo que mi primer proyecto JavaFX con Maven fue un dolor de cabeza para configurarlo, en esta prueba me creó un proyecto funcional sin ningún tipo de error en la compilación.

Comment: Perdón, no te crea una clase `Main`, sino una clase `App` que sería el punto de entrada de tu proyecto.

Comment: Depende de la funciones que necesites, de [esta lista](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-library-v6-requirements) por lo menos necesitas las de commons, jrxml y pdf.